# Binary search between two files in C

Tags: c, monkey, sequencing

I'm trying to apply some previously written code to some DNA sequencing data that I have collected. I would like to match my sequencing reads to a document containing specific barcodes and output the number of hits for each match. I am having some very basic trouble with calling the two files to compare. The code compiles, however, when I try to call the file "MOBYtest" in line 77, the output is 0, which indicates that the file is not being called appropriately. Does anyone have any insight into how I can incorporate the two files into the following code?

```
####################################################################################################
#### Supplementary File 2, barcodebin.c ############################################################
####
#### Barcode assigned to a gene using standard binary search
####
#### Can Alkan
#### 2010
####################################################################################################
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct spair{
  char *name;
  char *seq;
  int count;
}_spair;


int binSearch(char *seq, int s, int e);
void revcomp(char *s, char *r);

static int maxfunc(const void *p1, const void *p2);

struct spair **seqs;
int seqlen;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  FILE *fp;
  int i;
  char fname[100];
  int nseq;
  char sequence[100]; char name[100];
  char sname[100];
  char revseq[100];
  int retCode=100000;
  int s, e; int olds;
  int found;
  int crop;
  int len;
  int longest_barcode=0;
  int fastq=0;
  char line[1000];
  int loop_done=0;
  int crop_lim;
  int min_barcode = 5;
  int verbose = 0;
  
  fname[0]=0; nseq = 0; sname[0]=0;
  for (i=1;i<argc;i++){
    if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-i"))
      strcpy(fname, argv[i+1]);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))
      strcpy(sname, argv[i+1]);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-n"))
      nseq = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-m"))
      min_barcode = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-v"))
      verbose = 1;
  }

  if (fname[0]==0 || nseq==0 || sname[0]==0) return 0;

  fp = fopen(fname, "MOBYtest");
  if ( !fp ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s\n", fname);
    return 255;
  }
    

  i=0;

  seqs = (struct spair ** ) malloc (sizeof (struct spair *) * nseq);
 
  if (verbose) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Loading  %d sequences ..", nseq);
  }

  while (fscanf(fp, ">%s\n%s\n", name, sequence) > 0 ){
    seqlen=strlen(sequence);
    if (seqlen > longest_barcode) longest_barcode = seqlen;
    if (seqlen>=3){
      seqs[i] = (struct spair * ) malloc (sizeof (struct spair));
      seqs[i]->name = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen (name)+1));
      seqs[i]->seq = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) * (2*seqlen+1));
      seqs[i]->count = 0;

      strcpy(seqs[i]->seq, sequence);
      strcpy(seqs[i]->name, name);

      i++;
    }
  }

  nseq = i;

  qsort(seqs, nseq, sizeof(struct spair *), maxfunc);

  if (verbose) {
    fprintf(stderr, "  done. %d left. Longest barcode: %d bp\n", nseq, longest_barcode);
  }

  fclose(fp);

  fp = fopen(sname, "r");
  if ( !fp ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s\n", sname);
    return 255;
  }


  while (fscanf(fp, "%s\n%s\n", name, sequence) > 0){



    if (name[0]=='@'){
      fgets(line, 1000, fp); // + line
      fgets(line, 1000, fp); // quality line
    }


    sequence[longest_barcode]=0;

    strcpy(revseq, sequence);
    s = 0, e = nseq; retCode = 10000; olds=-10;
    found=0;


    crop = 0;
    len = strlen(revseq);

    crop_lim = longest_barcode - min_barcode + 1; // ad hoc

    while (crop<crop_lim){
      revseq[len-crop]=0;

      while (s<e && retCode!=0){
    retCode=binSearch(revseq, s, e);
    if (retCode < 0){e = (s+e)/2;}
    else if (retCode > 0){olds=s; s = (s+e)/2;}
    
    else if (retCode == 0){

      seqs[(s+e)/2]->count++;
      crop = crop_lim+1;
      break;
    }
    
    if (s>=e || s==olds){

      crop++;

      s = 0, e = nseq; retCode = 10000; olds=-10;
      break;

    }
    
      }
    }

  }
 
  if (verbose) {
    fprintf(stderr, "  done.\n");
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "Barcode_Name\tBarcode_Length\tFrequency\n");
  for (i=0;i<nseq;i++)
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\t%d\t%d\n", seqs[i]->name, strlen(seqs[i]->seq), seqs[i]->count);
}

int binSearch(char *seq, int s, int e){
  int med = (s+e)/2;
  
  int ret;

  ret = strcmp(seq, seqs[med]->seq);

  return ret;
}

void revcomp(char *s, char *r){
  int len = strlen(s);
  int  i;

  for (i=0;i<len;i++){
    switch(s[i]){
    case 'A': r[len-i-1] = 'T'; break;
    case 'T': r[len-i-1] = 'A'; break;
    case 'C': r[len-i-1] = 'G'; break;
    case 'G': r[len-i-1] = 'C'; break;
    default:  r[len-i-1] = s[i]; break;
    }
  }
  r[len]=0;
}


static int maxfunc(const void *p1, const void *p2){
  struct spair *a, *b;

  int ret;
  a = *((struct spair **)p1);
  b = *((struct spair **)p2);

  ret = strcmp(a->seq, b->seq);

  return ret;


}
```

Comment: "I am having some very basic trouble with calling the two files to compare" <- Please elaborate regarding what you are trying to do that fails. Does this code compile? What happens when you invoke the compiled program?

Comment: Yes, the code compiles. There are two files I would like to call, one is MOBYtest which contains my sequencing reads and the second is the list of barcodes to match it to. I have attempted to call the file "MOBYtest" however, I am only getting an output of 0 when I run the code, which indicates that the file is not being read. I need it to call two files, however, I only see one obvious spot where the code is calling for a file. The code was published on a similar experiment as mine, so I think it should work for my purposes, I just need to start by understanding how to call each file
Thanks!

Comment: Please put this extra text into your answer. Also use the preformatted-paragraph styling to show us your command-line, exactly. Then write what the printed output was, and what the return value was (if you know how to check the return value).

Comment: Thank you, einpoklum, I really appreciate your help. I have tried to edit my question to include the information you requested, but I am unsure how to check a return value.

Comment: I think I figured out what's wrong.

Comment: Replace `fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s\n", fname);` with `perror(fname)`, and the error message may be much more useful.

Comment: Thank you William Pursell, I replaced the line you suggested, but I still am getting the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
fp = fopen(fname, "MOBYtest");
```

that's not how you call `fopen()`. If you look at the [man page for `fopen()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) you'll see the signature:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *pathname, const char *mode);
```

So, you don't "plug" your filename into the program, you pass it when invoking, i.e. if you compiled this file as `my_prog`, you would execute something like:

```
my_prog -i "MOBYtest" -s "my_list_of_barcodes_I_guess" -n 100
```

and the `MOBYtest` string would come into `fopen()` via the `pathname` parameter. Now, the *mode* for opening the file is one or "r", "w", a" etc., which correspond to "read", "write", "append" etc. Again, see the man page.

---

Some more advice:

- [Always turn the warning flags on during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings). You definitely got some warnings about your code - heed them.
- Use common/standard facilities for common tasks such as argument parsing - don't write your own parsing code. Specifically, you could use [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html), available on any POSIX system; or maybe try  [argparse](https://github.com/Cofyc/argparse) (a library available on GitHub, could be a bit challenging for newbie to set up and include in the build).

Comment: Thank you einpoklum, I'm going to try to incorporate your advice.